# getautosuggestdata type is not supported

Tags: asp.net, autosuggest

I am using Google AutoSuggestData. It's implemented fine and working in a page
but when trying to implement in another page it gives error

> system exception :getautosuggestdata
>   type is not supported

Comment: Can you post the code (at least the line where you put in the autosuggesteddata, plus a few lines before and a few lines after)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to include the `DataType` property when including the control in the new page. If you set a value that it doesn't recognise, you get an exception like "getautosuggestdata type 'Foo' is not supported", so I guess the error see is what will happen when the property is empty.